# $2$-norm of the identity matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-norms, spectral-norm

I want to show that $\|I_n\|_2=1$ but I'm not sure how should I calculate its largest singular value, am I supposed to use SDV decomposition each time I want to calculate a two-norm?

According to my book (*numerical linear algebra by Gill*), one norm (the maximum absolute column sum) and infinity norm (the maximum absolute row sum) for the following matrix would be $1$, right? What about its Frobenius norm?

Comment: The Frobenius norm would be $\sqrt{n}$. Is $\lVert A\rVert_2$ defined as $$\sup_{\lVert x\rVert_2 = 1} \lVert Ax\rVert_2,$$ that is, as the operator norm with respect to the $\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert_2$-norms of the domain and codomain, or in some other way?

Comment: @DanielFischer: In my book, it's defined as follows: $\|A\|_2$ is the largest singular value.

Comment: Singular value is the same as eigenvalue, isn't it?

Comment: @Berci: Is it? I didn't know that.

Comment: @Berci No, singular values are always non-negative, and the matrix need not be square/the operator need not be an endomorphism. And if it is an endomorphism, you generally consider two different orthonormal bases for the singular value decomposition.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the identity matrix is a diagonal matrix with non-negative diagonal elements, hence its singular value decomposition is simply

$$I_n = I_n \cdot I_n \cdot I_n^\ast,$$

all its singular values are $1$, whence $\lVert I_n\rVert_2 = 1$.

> am I supposed to use SDV decomposition each time I want to calculate a two-norm?

Not necessarily. Note that an alternative way to define the two-norm is

$$\lVert A\rVert_2 = \sup_{\lVert x\rVert_2 = 1} \lVert Ax\rVert_2.$$

With the singular value decomposition

$$A = U\Sigma V^\ast,$$

we obtain

$$\begin{align}
\sup_{\lVert x\rVert_2 = 1} \lVert Ax \rVert_2 &= \sup_{\lVert x\rVert_2 = 1} \lVert U\Sigma V^\ast x\rVert_2\\
&= \sup_{\lVert x\rVert_2 = 1} \lVert \Sigma V^\ast x\rVert_2\\
&= \sup_{\lVert y\rVert_2 = 1} \lVert \Sigma y\rVert_2,
\end{align}$$

since $U$ and $V^\ast$ are norm-preserving, and it is not hard to see that $\sup_{\lvert y\rVert_2 = 1} \lVert \Sigma y\rVert_2$ is the largest singular value.

This supremum is in general not easy to find, but with that, we can see

$$\lVert A\rVert_2^2 = \sup_{\lVert x\rVert_2 = 1} \lVert Ax\rVert_2^2 = \sup_{\lVert x\rVert_2 = 1} \langle Ax, Ax\rangle = \sup_{\lVert x\rVert_2 = 1} \langle x, A^\ast Ax\rangle,$$

and $A^\ast A$ is a positive semidefinite hermitian matrix, thus $\lVert A\rVert_2^2$ is the largest eigenvalue of $A^\ast A$, which sometimes is easier to compute.

However, computing operator norms like $\lVert A\rVert_2$ is in general not a trivial task.

Regarding the Frobenius norm,

$$\lVert I_n \rVert_F = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \delta_{ij}^2} = \sqrt{n},$$

where $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker symbol, $\delta_{ij} = 1$ if $i = j$, and $\delta_{ij} = 0$ if $i\neq j$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you mean *transpose* by the asterisk sign?

Comment: Transpose, or conjugate transpose, that depends on whether we're working with real or complex scalars.

Comment: Right, could you explain the above formula for two-norm which you mentioned in your comment as well?

Comment: Explain in what way? It's the supremum of the lengths of the images of the unit sphere, also the smallest constant $C \geqslant 0$ such that you have $\lVert Ax\rVert_2 \leqslant C\cdot \lVert x\rVert_2$ for all $x$, the maximal "stretching" of the map (induced by) $A$.

Comment: OK, then it's way too mathematical. I'd compute SVD decomposition instead.